# MVC Entity Framework WillCascadeOnDelete do not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first, cascading-deletes

Im am doing an `MVC` `Entity Framework 6` `DataBase First` App.

I have two tables.. `Groups` And `MemberGroups`, with a relationship one to many.

```
Foreign Key can not be Null
```

When I Add the database to my Application. The `.Edmx` is generated with the `Context.cs` file

```html
 public partial class PortalEntities : DbContext
    {
        public VIvaVoceEntities()
            : base("name=PortalEntities")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
          public virtual DbSet<GroupMembers> GroupMembers { get; set; }
          
         public virtual DbSet<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Under `.tt` folder It was generated the `class` for each table.

```html
 public partial class Groups
 {
     public long Group_id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<GroupMembers> GroupMembers { get; set; }
  }
          
  public partial class GroupMembers
  {
      public long MemberGroup_ID { get; set; }
      public long Group_id { get; set; }
   }
```

I am trying to do a `Delete on cascade`... When I delete a Group, I want to delete all Members in that group. 
So in `OnModelCreating` in `Context.cs` file I add everthing I found in order to delete on cascade, but nothing Works.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```html
   modelBuilder.Entity<Groups>()
             .HasMany(e => e.GroupMembers)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Groups)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
 ---------------------------------           
            
 modelBuilder.Entity<Groups>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.GroupMembers)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);            
 
 ---------------------------------
   
modelBuilder.Entity<Groups>().HasMany(i => i.GroupMembers)
            .WithOptional(i => i.Groups)
            .HasForeignKey(i => i.Group_id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);    

 ---------------------------------
            
modelBuilder.Entity<Groups>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.GroupMembers)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Group_id )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Here is the code  I use to delete it.

```html
  var master = _db.Set<Groups>().Include(m => m.GroupMembers).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Group_id == 2);
            _db.Set<Groups>().Remove(master);
            _db.SaveChanges();
```

I have the following error...

```html
"The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted."
```

It seems that it is not trying to delete child records. It is trying to Update with Null

How is the correct way to do it.?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this code. It is not cascade as I want to but it is the best way I found.

```html
 public void Delete(long Group_id)
{
      Groups group = _db.Set<Groups>().Include(m => m.GroupMembers).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Group_id == Group_id);
      _db.GroupMembers.RemoveRange(group.GroupMembers);
      _db.SaveChanges();

      _db.Entry(group).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
      _db.SaveChanges();
   }
```